# SCRIPT5022: Argument 'module' is not a function, got undefined angular.js, line 975 character 5

Tags: angularjs

I am facing below exception in IE-8 when I am loading the angular related page. It works fine in other browsers. Any specific reason?

```
SCRIPT5022: Argument 'module' is not a function, got undefined 
angular.js, line 975 character 5
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had this same issue (when on IE < 9) and it took me forever to track it down...

```
angular.module('app', ['app.directives', 'app.filters', 'app.services', ]);
```

Note the trailing comma after 'app.services'.

Comment: Very helpful to know that IE<9 doesn't support trailing commas (and also mind-boggling). I usually use them everywhere because it makes adding items easier.

Comment: Thanks for that! IE8 is such a joke! Though so many clients are still running it!

Comment: Thanks for me it was a leading comma: `[ , 'app.directives', 'app.filters', 'app.services']`

Answer (score 1):

I get errors like that when I try to inline end the script tag causing IE to not load all my scripts. Check if you have end tags for all your script includes.

To illustrate:

```
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"/> <!-- THIS IS A PROBLEM FOR IE -->
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
```

On IE9 this will result in:

```
SCRIPT5022: No module: myApp.filters 
angular.min.js, line 17 character 195
```

Not entirely the same, but I can't test it on IE8. On Chrome however, this works perfectly. The weird thing about this, is actually the thing it can't seem to find, is in the script following the one with the inline ending. I can't really explain that.

Now, when I close the script tag like this:

```
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script> <!-- THIS WORKS -->
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
```

It works like a charm.

To sum it up, AngularJS tries to find your module called 'module', but is not able to find it. Probably due to a script that is not loaded. Try to find a script tag which closes inline, and end it as descibed above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might cause this is using keywords for object properties. I had three modules with the error above:

```
statistic.import = !statistic.import;

default: $scope.newGrid.default

$scope.data = JSON.stringify({export: exportParams})
```

The offending properties being **import**, **default** and **export**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still walking around same problem, but i've found up a possible cause:

when you declare any angular module you must inject dependences some like this:

```
angular.module('MyStore', ['ng','ngRoute']);
```

if you need invoke that module from another place to perform any action you probably mismatch if you attempt to inject dependences again... then you must call it by its name like this:

```
angular.module('myStore')
```

otherwise you will exploit your brain looking for the solution.

I hope it helps!